# Electrum paper wallet exploit

Tags: wallet, security, electrum, paper-wallet, hardware-wallet

I want to generate a paper wallet with Electrum using my personal computer that I've been using for a few years now, meaning that I'm online with it daily.

I know that the optimal solution is to use a computer that has never been connected to the internet, but I'm curious if there are any reports of malware compromising this kind of setup.
(I'm considering this setup because where I'm from it is not so easy/fast to get a hardware wallet)

1. Go offline
2. Generate seed words
3. Copy them to paper
4. Delete wallet from computer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's more safe to do it on "clean" operating system.
I can propose another solution:

1. Prepare DVD or USB stick with Ubuntu operating system
2. Start live session of Ubuntu from DVD or USB stick on your computer
3. Download Electrum AppImage from official Electrum website
4. Run Electrum, generate seed
5. Switch off computer, all data will be lost